# South: Why the "column <colname> contains null values" error when a valid one-off default value has been provided

Tags: django, django-south

Originally, the model attribute ***location*** for ***Item*** class was defined like the following:

```
location = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name='+', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

It then got redefined to:

```
location = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name='+', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Because of the change in definition, I executed South's *schemamigration*. South responded with

> The field 'Item.location' does not have a default specified, yet is
>   NOT NULL. Since you are making this field non-nullable, you MUST
>   specify a default value to use for existing rows.

I picked choice '2' and provided the PK (integer) of an existing *Location*.

But when I ran *migrate*, I got the following error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "location_id" contains null values

I don't understand why I got this error when I had provided a valid default location PK. This is really mind-boggling. Please help~ Thanks.

Migration spec:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Changing field 'Item.location'
    db.alter_column('lend_borrow_item', 'location_id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(default=11, to=orm['app_name.Location']))
def backwards(self, orm):
    # Changing field 'Item.location'
    db.alter_column('lend_borrow_item', 'location_id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(null=True, to=orm['app_name.Location']))

models = {
    'app_name.location': {
        'Meta': {'ordering': "['name']", 'object_name': 'Location'},
        'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'})
    },
    'lend_borrow.item': {
        'Meta': {'object_name': 'Item'},
        'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
        'location': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'related_name': "'+'", 'to': "orm['app_name.Location']"}),
        'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '50'})
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the migration spec look like?

Comment: @DmitryBeransky - I have added the migration spec to my post. Please let me know if you can see anything that might have caused the problem. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem seems to be caused by [South Defect #627](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/627)

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @Intenex - I am assuming that you get this error because you altered some column, `my_col`, from `null=True` to `null=False`. If that's the case, a quick hack is to populate the rows whose `my_col` is NULL with empty string. After you have done that, you should be able to execute `migrate` without the error.

Comment: I fixed that by manually changing every null entry like this: http://pastebin.com/3esfyiDq

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution has already been posted, but you might want to simply add a line to the relevant migration.

```
...
class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        ...
        # Add the following line before the ``alter_column`` command
        orm['your_app.YourModel'].objects.filter(
            your_field__isnull=True).update(your_field=any_default_value)

        # This is the line that causes the exception
        db.alter_column(u'your_app.YourModel', 'your_field', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.Whatever')())
        ...
    ...
```